# Do something immediately after posting in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, so I was wondering, how can I display something immediately after posting. At this moment I have something like this.

```
$('#cur_select').on('change', function() {
    $.post( "getTable.php", { value: this.value }).done(function( data ) 
    {
        $("#mytable").html(data);
    });
});
```

It takes some time to get the data from PHP, so I want to notify the user (by changing text of a label), that the site is in the process of getting the data. Where can I put such code here?

Comment: Right after the `$.post` block?

Comment: Yes, what is the syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post will update when it updates. The callback function that you have after .done() will be called once $.post is finished. As that is happening, javascript will carry on. So whatever you want to do (maybe have a spinner animation within #mytable as it waits for its data) can be placed immediately after the $.post, or even before.

```
$('#cur_select').on('change', function() {
    $.post( "getTable.php", { value: this.value }).done(function( data ) 
    {
        $("#mytable").html(data);
    });

    $("#mytable").css("background-image", "url(/myLoadingSpinner.gif)"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that just before you do POST call or you can put your code just after POST call (because POST.done is asynchronous and code is moving immediately along).

```
$('#cur_select').on('change', function() {
    //Here
    $.post( "getTable.php", { value: this.value }).done(function( data ) 
    {
        $("#mytable").html(data);
    });
    //Or here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the two functions ajaxStart and ajaxComplete in jquery. These two functions will help you to do the change like showing a spinner or showing some text to the user before the processing and hide it once the data is retrieved. Thank you.